# How to get the architectural size with assembly?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture

On 32 bit machine ,it should be 4 bytes.

On 64 bit,it should be 8 bytes.

How to get it with assembly?

Comment: The question is based on a false premise - there are plenty of CPUs where the register size is not the same as the notional architectural size. There are also architectures with address registers and general purpose registers which are different sizes.

Comment: @Paul R,I realized that,and rephrased my question:)

Comment: @compile-fan: you already know the architectural size at compile-time/assembly-time - there is never going to be a case where you need to determine this at run-time.

Comment: @Paul R,I need to do this so that the assembly code can work on both 32/64 bit.Am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: @compile-fan: yes, you just need to use preprocessor macros so that you can conditionally assemble for 32 bit and 64 bit. BTW, if the question is specific to x86 and x86-64 only then you should probably flag it as such - there's a much bigger and more complex world beyond Intel x86.

Comment: But in my specific case,I want to get the architectural size in assembly,not C macros..

Comment: @compile-fan: preprocessor defines are usually available in assembly source just as they are in C, C++ and other languages - you haven't actually said what OS or tools you are using though, so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: @Paul,it's not available in gdb...

Comment: @compile-fan: gdb is a *debugger* - if you're writing asm then you'll be compiling/assembling it with gcc/gas/gas/nasm or similar compiler/assembler.

Answer (score -1):

Read data from memory. The number of bytes read is what you're looking for. Don't ask how to do it because you didn't specify any particular CPU.
*Anyway*, if you code for 32 bit machines it will run on 64 bit too, while the opposite isn't true.
And, since you're programming in asm, you should have different coding for 32 and 64 bit machines to take advantage of the CPU's power. Think about the `strlen()` function, the 64 bit version is as twice as fast as the 32 bit version; they're both based on the same algo, but are coded slightly different.

Comment: This is nonsense.  Do you mean zero a register and then load from a block of all-ones, and see how many bits of the register are all-ones?  Even if that worked, it's a terrible answer.  The machine-size is always known at assemble time, so doing any kind of run-time check is dumb.  (except maybe in some x86 vs. x86-64 code-injection scenario where the same fragment of machine-code could maybe be crafted to work on i386 and amd64).